# JVM crashes when trying to compile maven plugin in OSX

Tags: java, macos, maven, maven-plugin

I am trying to create a basic mojo (just hello world). However when I try to compile the maven plugin the JVM crashes like this:

```
[INFO] --- maven-plugin-plugin:3.3:descriptor (default-descriptor) @ xyz-compiler-plugin ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to read mojo metadata.
[INFO] Applying mojo extractor for language: java
[INFO] Mojo extractor for language: java found 0 mojo descriptors.
[INFO] Applying mojo extractor for language: bsh
[INFO] Mojo extractor for language: bsh found 0 mojo descriptors.
[INFO] Applying mojo extractor for language: java-annotations
[INFO] Mojo extractor for language: java-annotations found 1 mojo descriptors.
2016-06-13 22:14:58.813 java[36254:2194441] Apple AWT Internal Exception: Critical error: required built-in appearance SystemAppearance not found
2016-06-13 22:14:58.814 java[36254:2194441] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Critical error: required built-in appearance SystemAppearance not found'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9997a4f2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8f27bf7e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff999e14bd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8f7a640b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8f7a6303 dispatch_once_f + 67
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff981c12ad +[NSAppearance _defaultAppearance] + 22
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff981c113b +[NSAppearance appearanceNamed:] + 24
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff981c09ee +[NSWindow initialize] + 166
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8f2723c8 _class_initialize + 711
    9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8f271d08 lookUpImpOrForward + 179
    10  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8f26c591 objc_msgSend + 209
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff981c05ed +[NSApplication initialize] + 719
    12  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8f2723c8 _class_initialize + 711
    13  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8f272156 _class_initialize + 85
    14  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8f271d08 lookUpImpOrForward + 179
    15  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8f26c591 objc_msgSend + 209
    16  libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x0000000125cef2dc -[AWTStarter starter:] + 266
    17  Foundation                          0x00007fff8a0b3f5e __NSThreadPerformPerform + 279
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9990f881 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff998eefbc __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff998ee4df __CFRunLoopRun + 927
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff998eded8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
    22  java                                0x0000000103edc463 CreateExecutionEnvironment + 871
    23  java                                0x0000000103ed81ac JLI_Launch + 1952
    24  java                                0x0000000103ede4c0 main + 101
    25  java                                0x0000000103ed7a04 start + 52
    26  ???                                 0x000000000000000c 0x0 + 12
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Abort trap: 6
```

The project has a parent POM project. I tried compiling from IntelliJ and the terminal but the issue remains the same.

My class is very simple

```
@Mojo(name="test")
public class BasicMojo extends AbstractMojo
{
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException
    {
        getLog().info( "Hello, this is a test." );
    }
}
```

My POM dependencies look like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xyz.network.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>xyz-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${micro.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Any clues?

Comment: Are you using Apple Java JDK or Oracle ? It looks you are using the Apple one..? Furthermore it would be helpful if you show your full pom file and the code also...

Comment: I am using Oracle's Java 8

Comment: Which version of JDK are you using? 1.8.?

Comment: yes it's Oracle's JDK 1.8

Comment: I asked for the exact version of JDK That you are using 1.8 was already clear but which version?

Comment: Can you try to use maven-plugin-plugin 3.4 instead ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I found the issue. I have set a environment variable called NEXT_ROOT and this causes the problem. If I unset it before executing my java program, I don't get this exception. Thanks everybody for your help.

Comment: same problem.. please also let us know how you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may be running low on memory, which forces the system to send out low-memory messages to instantiated view controllers. The default implementation of -didReceiveMemoryWarning clears out the view member variable. In theory, then next time the view is required, it should be re-instantiated, but you may have overridden something that's preventing that.